# Azure Function Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable object reference error in Azure portal

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have published my application to Azure Function using visual studio 2017. As the connection string from the Environment variable is always null, I am getting Object reference error in the logs, however, the application just works fine in local. Below is the piece of code where I get my connection string and logging it.

```
var helper = new Helper();

log.LogInformation($ "The connection string is {helper.GetConnectionString()}");

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(helper.GetConnectionString())) return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Connection is null");

var signalRService = new SignalRService(helper.GetConnectionString(), helper.GetIotHubName(), log);
log.LogInformation("SignalRService has been initialized");

await signalRService.SendRequest(helper.GetIotHubName(), data?.ToString());
log.LogInformation("SignalRService has been invoked successfully");

return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
```

Below is my helper class

```
public class Helper {
    private static readonly string connectionStringName = "AzureSignalRConnectionString";
    private static readonly string iotHubName = "iotHubName";

    public string GetConnectionString() {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(connectionStringName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    }
    public string GetIotHubName() {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(iotHubName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    }
}
```

When I monitor my function in the portal I can clearly see that the connection string is null. I have already given the connection string in the local.settings.json.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "iotHubName": "iot-hub",
    "AzureSignalRConnectionString": "connection string value",
    "MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES": 1
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 5181,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I am missing here. When it comes to the Environment variable, adding them to the local.settings.json alone will not help. When I log in to my Azure Function and checked the Application settings, I was not able to find the settings I had given in my local.settings.json. I did the following steps.

1. Opened the Publish settings in the Visual Studio
2. Clicked on Manage Application Settings, I was missing the values in the remote fields for both of my environment variables.
   [image]
3. Add the values in the remote fields.
4. Rebuild and Publish the Function App
5. Login to Azure Portal and make sure that the values are there under the application settings.

[image]